# How is a ten tefachim wall hard to use?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, architecture-design, real-estate, maseches-eruvin

The Gemara in [Eiruvin 77a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=77&format=text) says that when a ten tefachim wall is between two courtyards, but is less than that to one courtyard (the floor of the courtyard is heigher), we give it to the one which is lower since "this one [for whom the wall is 10 tefachim, the wall] is hard to use, while this one [,to whom the wall is less than 10 tefachim, the wall is] easy to use."

What??

10 tefachim is (at most) about 40 inches, which is about 3 feet. That's less than the height of a normal table. How is this difficult to use?

Comment: [People were shorter back then.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQHm7oItkdA)

Comment: @DoubleAA did they have smaller hands, too?

Comment: @DoubleAA so the tefachim must have been smaller.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I'm sorry I didn't make my question more clear.  You said the g'mara says "this one is hard to use"; I'm asking what the g'mara means by "use".  If it means "set things on" then I understand your question, as that's clearly of a height where you can set things on it.  Which is why I'm wondering if the g'mara could have meant something *else* by "use" (though I don't know what).  I haven't looked up the context, hence asking you since you're presumably there already.

Comment: @MonicaCellio it implies so (at least I think it does)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't know if it scaled perfectly proportionally, but yes.